# MS Access Can't go to specified record because of another control's VB where clause

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, navigation

I have a lookup listbox which is programmed to allow the user to find a specific record/help topic from the list and view it. Now when the list box is used the where clause locks in the record and the first, previous, next, last buttons freeze up and you cannot use them to go to a record. Is there a way to free up the functionality of the buttons to navigate through the records along with the where clause to select.
**Here is the code that operates the listbox selections:**

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
Dim myTopic As String
myTopic = "Select * from FormsHelpTable where ([ID] = " & Me.List35 & ")"
Me.Form.RecordSource = myTopic
Me.Comment.Requery
End Sub
```

I believe since the where clause locks in the selection in the box it does not allow navigation from other controls to interfere. What might be a way around this?
You get the runtime error:
You can't go to specified record. 
It appears not to be reading the other record in the source table named Help once it updates using the listbox.

Comment: I have tried to recreate the error and cannot. Once I select an item in the listbox, the rowsource correctly updates and only has one record in (the one I selected). Since I disabled 'Allow Additions' on the form, you can't even go to a blank record. Is this not the correct behavior?

Comment: My *listbox* has the rowsource of `SELECT [FormsHelpTable].[ID], [FormsHelpTable].[Title] FROM FormsHelpTable ORDER BY [ID];` and its control source is blank. I can upload my database if that would help?

Comment: Sure. Sorry I have not had time to check back sooner. Currently I have it so when I load the help form it allows you to use the controls but once it uses the selection from the listbox the where clause is met and the code refuses to allow the other buttons to work as if the code narrows what is available to look through in the list. I would like to be able to navigate through all options on the listbox with the other controls but it says you cannot go to the other records specified.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you want. Posting an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the recordset (this is the 'pool' of records which the form could display), you just need to go to the record the user selects from the listbox.

**Method 1** (probably the easiest way if your listbox is in the same order as the records of your form)

Use this code:

```
Private Sub lstSelect_AfterUpdate()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "HelpForm", acGoTo, Me.lstSelect.ListIndex + 1

End Sub
```

You need to ensure that:

- The recordset of the form is ordered the same as the listbox. So, for example, you could order both by `ID`, or by `Title`.

Note that the `+1` comes from the fact that the `ListIndex` starts at 0, whereas the record indexes start at 1.

---

**Method 2**

1. Ensure each record's `Title` is unique (set No Duplicates on this field).
2. Change your listbox to return the `Title` of the record, rather than it's `ID`.

Then use this:

```
Private Sub lstSelect_AfterUpdate()

    Me.Title.SetFocus

    DoCmd.FindRecord Me.lstSelect

    Me.lstSelect.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Things to note:

- It works by searching the *field with focus* for the string specified. That's why we have to `SetFocus` on the `Title` textbox on our form.
- We could use `ID` instead, (which would mean we could have duplicate titles if we wanted), but then we would have to have an `ID` control on the form to `SetFocus` to. You can't hide this control either, because it needs to have focus whilst using `FindRecord`.

---

**Update: Method 1 with reverse-selection**

Add an Event Procedure in the `Form_Current` event, with this code. Then update the code in the `lstSelect_AfterUpdate` procedure as shown after.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me.lstSelect = Me.lstSelect.Column(0, Form.CurrentRecord - 1)

End Sub
```

*Note that, depending on how your lstSelect is set up, it may be* `Column(1, Form.CurrentRecord - 1)` *instead. Read on for details!*

```
Private Sub lstSelect_AfterUpdate()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "HelpForm", acGoTo, Me.lstSelect.ListIndex + 1

    Me.lstSelect = Me.lstSelect.Column(0, Form.CurrentRecord - 1)

End Sub
```

Explanation of new lines:

- The `Form_Current` event fires every time we go to a new record. We need to look at the index of the record (ie. the position of it in the recordset), which we get by using `Form.CurrentRecord`. We then want to make the listbox select that record. However, we can't use `me.lstSelect.ListIndex` as before, because that is a *read-only* property (we can access it to read it, but we can't set it).
- Therefore, we use `me.lstSelect.Column(colNum,rowNum)` instead, where we specify a column number and a row number. If your listbox has two columns (eg. `ID` and `Title`), we want to choose the second column. The index starts at 0, so we would use a value of 1. If, like my `lstSelect`, you only have one column (`Title`) then we use 0. *Note:* it doesn't matter if a column is hidden (ie. has width 0). It still 'counts'.
- The row number is `Form.CurrentRecord - 1`. Remember that the forms recordset index starts at 1, but the index of our listbox starts at 0; hence the `- 1`.
- So why do we need a duplicate of this new row in the `AfterUpdate` event? Try and comment it out to see what happens if we don't put it in. It's has to do with the `Form_Current` event firing after we use the listbox.

Comment: Does this switch the title highlighted item around too as you would navigate with the control buttons?

Comment: No, but that's easily done. I can update the answer with the extra code if you'd like?

Comment: This works great! Thanks... Actually that would be nice to have in method1 the updated version which will highlight wherever the next/prev buttons take you on the list.

Comment: Mark where do you learn these commands? Did you use online tutorials or just in the office? I would appreciate to know where to learn the VBA.

Comment: I've added a new section at the bottom - Method 1 with reverse-selection. The MSDN is a good place to start, but can be a little in depth for beginners. Really, reading Stack Overflow and just playing around in Access is the best way.

Comment: I really like this new code except I have one issue, the listbox sorts the items in ascending order A-Z, the table is not sorted A-Z so it does not match the item number. When you click the second item on the listbox it routes it to the wrong help comment. So I either can delete my Primary key and then assign the topic as such verbatim (which kind of makes keeping an index difficult)  or try to remove the sort somehow.

Comment: Change the recordset of the form (in form properties window) so that it has the same `ORDER BY` as the listbox

Comment: I found the ORDER BY clause in the Form properties window under Data tab and wrote: FormsHelpTable but it still is not working... is that where?

Comment: I set the listbox to unsorted in the record source query. Now it works yet having it unsorted is a little clumsy for a user to navigate through. I should figure out how to.

Comment: The easiest way might be to click in the Record Source box of your form properties, then click the `...` button which appears. In query view you can now sort your records.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with a union clause in the SQL lookup code. The UNION ALL clause and the following union on the table used in the other part had allowed all the records to be used.